# How to create slugs in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, slug

I'm trying to develop an e-com website in Laravel 5 (Since it required lot of customization, I decided not to use Magento or OpenCart).

The problem I'm facing is to creating category and product URLs from slugs.

For example, one URL can be:

http://somewebsite.com/products/lenovo-yoga-500

But I want to make URL like:

http://somewebsite.com/lenovo-yoga-500

I tried to create a route like:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'BaseController@route');
```

and in the route() method, I tried:

```
function route($route){
    $product = Product::where(array('slug' => $slug))->first();

    if(isset($product))
    .....
    else
    .....
```

but first of all, the value is not getting passed to variable '$slug' and secondly I want to redirect the request to another route after checking the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go with the first URL (product/{slug}) because the way you have it setup with the slug as the first parameter, every route you make for any page will be interpreted as the slug.

Either way, fix your controller method as such

```
function route($slug){
    $product = Product::where(array('slug' => $slug))->first();

    if(isset($product))
    .....
    else
    .....
```

The documentation covers everything you are asking for here, so please read through about redirecting to routes.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it like Magento does, you need to add a new `product-routes.php` file that will be rebuilt.

First instruct `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` to load your dynamic route file thus:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        require base_path('resources/routes/product-routes.php');
    });
}
```

Next: Rebuild `product-routes.php` automatically on save or when the user requests it in the backend to include all product slug routes and to load the product by slug.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

in Product-model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName() {
    return 'slug';
}
```

in routes:

```
Route::get('{product}', 'ProductController@product');
```

in ProductController:

```
public function product(Product $product) {
    $product->doSomething();
}
```

Note that the route should be last in the routes-file so any other route has chance to match before that.

Answer (score 0):

### You must use this Route

```
Route::get('/sample/show/{sample : slug}',[SampleController::class]);
```

Enter the model of the controller and set the value of getRouteKeyName equal to slug such as:

```
public function getRouteKeyName(){return 'slug';}
```

---

### Custom Keys & Scoping

When implicitly binding multiple Eloquent models in a single route definition, you may wish to scope the second Eloquent model such that it must be a child of the previous Eloquent model. For example, consider this route definition that retrieves a blog post by slug for a specific user:

```
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;

Route::get('/users/{user}/posts/{post:slug}', function (User $user, Post $post) {    return $post;});
```